# Sample task application with drag and drop

Tags: ember.js

app.js

```
App = Em.Application.create();

App.IndexRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
   return {
    newTasks: Em.A([
      {id: 1, name: "Task 1"},
      {id: 2, name: "Task 2"},
      {id: 3, name: "Task 3"}
    ]),
    inProgressTasks: Em.A([
      {id: 4, name: "Task 4"},
      {id: 5, name: "Task 5"}
    ]),
    doneTasks: Em.A([
     {id: 6, name: "Task 6"}
    ])
    };
    }
   });

App.IndexController = Em.Controller.extend({
  actions: {
    moveTask: function(taskID, from, to){
      var model = this.get('model'); 
      var task = model[from].findProperty('id', parseInt(taskID, 10));
      model[to].pushObject(task);
      model[from].removeObject(task);
    }
  }

});

App.TaskContainerComponent = Em.Component.extend({
  classNames: ['col-xs-4', 'taskContainer'],
  isOverdrop: false,
  classNameBindings: ['isOverdrop:isOverdrop'],

  setOverdropIfNotOriginator: function(event, valueToSet){
    var data = JSON.parse(event.dataTransfer.getData('text/data'));
    if(data.stage !== this.get('stage')) {
      this.set('isOverdrop', valueToSet);
    }
  },

  dragEnter: function(event) {
    this.setOverdropIfNotOriginator(event, true);
  },

  dragLeave: function(event){
    this.setOverdropIfNotOriginator(event, false);
  },

  dragOver: function(event){
    this.setOverdropIfNotOriginator(event, true);    
    event.preventDefault();
  },

  drop: function(event) {
    var data = JSON.parse(event.dataTransfer.getData('text/data'));
    if(data.stage === this.get('stage')) return;

    // from: data.stage, to: this.get('stage')
    this.sendAction('action', data.id, data.stage, this.get('stage'));
    this.set('isOverdrop', false);
  }

});

App.DragTaskComponent = Em.Component.extend({
  dragStart: function(event) {
    var data = { id: this.get('task.id'), stage: this.get('stage')};
    event.dataTransfer.setData('text/data', JSON.stringify(data));
  }
});
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Mini Scrumboard</title>
  <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
    <div class="contents">
      <div class="row">
        {{ task-container containerTitle="New" stage="newTasks" tasks=model.newTasks 
           action="moveTask" on="drop"}}
        {{ task-container containerTitle="In Progress" stage="inProgressTasks" 
           tasks=model.inProgressTasks action="moveTask" on="drop" }}
        {{ task-container containerTitle="Done" stage="doneTasks" tasks=model.doneTasks 
           action="moveTask" on="drop" }}
      </div>
      <br>
      <br>
    </div>
  </script>

  <!-- Properties: task, stage -->  
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="components/drag-task">
    <div class="task" draggable="true">
      {{task.name}}
    </div>
  </script> 

  <!-- Properties: containerTitle, stage, tasks -->
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="components/task-container">
    <h3>{{containerTitle}}</h3>
    {{#each task in tasks}}
      {{drag-task task=task stage=stage}}
    {{/each}}
  </script> 

  <script src="js/libs/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/handlebars-1.1.2.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/ember-1.5.1.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  <!-- to activate the test runner, add the "?test" query string parameter -->
  <script src="tests/runner.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have this working perfectly fine on my local box, but it is errorring out on jsbin.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/movex/4/edit?html,css,js,output

I am guessing that the issue has to do with parsing the output from the drag and drop, but have no clue where to go with this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

UPDATE: The JSBin version even works fine on the FF on the Mac, but not on Safari or Chrome... :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason it was not working is because of the very unexpected way that [the drag and drop specifications](http://developers.whatwg.org/dnd.html#concept-dnd-p) work. The problem is that in the `drag`, `dragEnter`, `dragLeave`, `dragOver` and `dragEnd` events the dragTransfer data is in protected mode. Which again according to the spec means.

> the data itself is unavailable and no new data can be added.

It seems as though Mozilla exercised some common sense and didn't implement drag and drop in compliance with the spec. Which explains why it was working in Firefox for you, but nowhere else.

To get your jsbin working I added a `theData` element to your index controller and did the setting and getting of the JSON values against that.

Here is the working version. http://emberjs.jsbin.com/dasonona/1/edit

Comment: This was clearly my issue. Here is the weird thing. Your jsbin seems to work, but this.set(key, value) in the component is not referring to the controller??!! It's referring to the component. So, not sure how it's working for you. I had to use this.get('targetObject') (and this.get('targetObject').get('targetObject') to access controller. Updated jsbin is here http://emberjs.jsbin.com/movex/5/edit?html,js,output