# Drag and drop into div

Tags: jquery, html, css, ember.js, drag-and-drop

I have been wondering if there is a way to drag and drop objects with different widths into div, so they will not impose on each other.

Let's say I have two divs and 5 objects. By div I mean something like timeline with one column for each 5 minutes. And objects are films, each film has his length, obviously. What I want is to drag these films and drop them into my timeline.

Sorry, English is not my native language. I made a picture, might help you understand my question.

[image]

P.S. I'm using ember.js, so if it has her own plugins or ways to do it, I would like to know.

Thanks!

Comment: ember dont have **her** own sortable plugins but [jquery sortable](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/) should work fine with views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented something similar in Ember.js (with some help from others) for a to do application dragging tasks back and forth. It basically comes down to a "container" type component and "task" (or film in your case) type component.

```
App.TaskContainerComponent = Em.Component.extend({
  classNames: ['col-xs-4', 'taskContainer'],
  isOverdrop: false,
  classNameBindings: ['isOverdrop:isOverdrop'],

  setOverdropIfNotOriginator: function(event, valueToSet){
    var data = JSON.parse(this.get("theData"));
    if(data.stage !== this.get('stage')) {
      this.set('isOverdrop', valueToSet);
    }
  },

  dragEnter: function(event) {
    this.setOverdropIfNotOriginator(event, true);
  },

  dragLeave: function(event){
    this.setOverdropIfNotOriginator(event, false);
  },

  dragOver: function(event){   
    event.preventDefault();
  },

  drop: function(event) {
    var data = JSON.parse(event.dataTransfer.getData('text/data'));
    if(data.stage === this.get('stage')) return;

    // from: data.stage, to: this.get('stage')
    this.sendAction('action', data.id, data.stage, this.get('stage'));
    this.set('isOverdrop', false);
  }
});

App.DragTaskComponent = Em.Component.extend({
  dragStart: function(event) {
    var data = { id: this.get('task.id'), stage: this.get('stage')};
    event.dataTransfer.setData('text/data', JSON.stringify(data));
    this.set("theData", JSON.stringify(data));
  }
});
```

The working solution ([here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/movex/5/edit?html,js,output)) is a little dated as it's using Ember.js 1.5, but I believe the main concepts still hold true.

See the original question on SO - [Sample task application with drag and drop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23794322/sample-task-application-with-drag-and-drop)

Answer (score 0):

There are many plugins that do this, for example http://farhadi.ir/projects/html5sortable/